# Merging 2 3d files into one

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, go, 3d

I am trying to merge 2 3d files into one. Any two 3d files .vox / .obj / .glb.

For my endeavor I can use js/ruby/golang(preferably).

What I want is something like this package over [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images). Sadly I can't find anything that I find useful. Is it even possible?

Node: I have no knowledge of 3d files, terminology and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine two different 3D files into one then they would have to be of the same file type to combined them. You can use this online editor to convert most voxel file formats to the main one you want to use [here](https://drububu.com/miscellaneous/voxelizer/?out=obj). For simplicity's sake, let's use the file format vox. Once you have converted all files into vox file format all you need to do is to launch the MagicaVoxel editor and import each file into the same scene. Then that's all you need to do. Now all the files are merged into one. Hopes this helps!